# How to compare hash of two structures?

Tags: solidity, struct, sha3, hash-algorithm, hash

```
function checkOffers() public returns (bool){
    uint256 a = sha256(offerFromProducer);
    uint256 b = sha256(offerFromConsumer);
    if(a == b){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

[image]

Is there some method to compare two structs in Solidity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return value of `sha256` is `bytes32`.  So use `bytes32 a = sha256(...)` and do the same for `b`.  This will fix the compiler errors and `a == b` will work.

But currently you cannot pass a struct to hashing functions like `sha256`, `keccak256`: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/980.  So generally the members of the structs have to be compared against each other.  A more specific question may help to uncover possible optimizations (for example, there may be ways to reduce the comparisons required depending on the app design).

Comment: Thanks! Can you give advice how to compare two structures with such fileds? 
`struct  Offer {
        uint amount;
        address transportCompany;
        string deliveryAddres;
}`